# Nodejs Post request is not working in Postman?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, postman, google-cloud-vision

I made a **Post API of google cloud vision for detecting image text**, Now I am trying to test this post API in **postman, but it is not working.** not getting any kind of response

```
app.post("/images", upload.single("file"), function (req, res) {
  client.textDetection(req.file.path)
  .then((results) => {
  res.send(results);
 })
 .catch((err) => {
  res.status(400).send(err);
 });
});
```

In **postman -**

using url - `http://localhost:8088/images`

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(err)` and checked if there is any error?

Comment: yes, no error even in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
  var oldpath = files.filetoupload.filepath;
  var newpath = 'C:/Users/Your Name/' + 
files.filetoupload.originalFilename;
  fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
    res.end();
  });
});
} else {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form- 
data">');
res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
res.write('<input type="submit">');
res.write('</form>');
return res.end();
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

`upload.single("file")` means that `multer` will look for a form part named `file`.

However, in your Postman screenshot, the name ("KEY") is empty.

Comment: should I write file? in the field of key?